# Directory listing for instead of index.html

Tags: python-3.x, localhost, httpserver

I put together a very basic website with an `index.html` page and a css folder. This is all contained within one main folder. However, when I try to run `python3 -m http.server` I end up being shown the "Directory listing for" rather than the contents of the `index.html` page and have to click once more to access the index.html. How can I have Python simply recognize the file from the beginning?

**System:** MacOS Sierra

**Python3 Version:** Latest

**Minimum Requirements for Replication:** Create a new folder with a new index.html and run `python3 -m http-server`

Comment: I just made a directory with a single `index.html` file in it and ran the command you specified and it worked for me, rendering the `index.html` page straight up. Odd.

Comment: @DanielPorteous Weird. Could it be an issue with what Python thinks it has permissions to do? I've had a number of permissions based issues with Python3 in the past.

Comment: If I remove read permissions on `index.html` it still doesn't show a directory listing, instead giving a 404. I'm really not too sure sorry.